# Make forumla in two seperate columns in the same column in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a formula that exists in two columns because I can't seem to figure out how to make it in simply one column.
The two formulas are in colomn: "Fragttype Paller" & "Fragttype koli"
However these two seperate formulas should be made as one formula in column "Fragttype simplified"

[Conditions for formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMUkJ.png)
The excel spreadsheet I've uploaded here https://easyupload.io/kpvqcv

Can someone help me?

BR
Luca

I tried simple copying both two formulas in excel on top of each summed in one column, but did not work

Comment: Can you post sample data in your question right here instead of linking to a download?

Comment: formula: 1 =IFS(AND(SEARCH("palle";[@[Pakke type]]);[@[Rumfang m³]]>0,5;[@[Rumfang m³]]<=1,5);"PLL1SE";AND(SEARCH("palle";[@[Pakke type]]);[@[Rumfang m³]]>1,5;[@[Rumfang m³]]<=2,5);"PLL2SE";AND(SEARCH("palle";[@[Pakke type]]);[@[Rumfang m³]]>2,5;[@[Rumfang m³]]<=3,5);"PLL3SE";AND(SEARCH("palle";[@[Pakke type]]);[@[Rumfang m³]]>3,5;[@[Rumfang m³]]<=4,5);"PLL4SE";AND(SEARCH("palle";[@[Pakke type]]);[@[Rumfang m³]]>4,5;[@[Rumfang m³]]<=5,5);"PLL5SE")

Comment: Formula 2 = =IFS(AND(SEARCH("Koli";[@[Pakke type]]);[@[DHL eller pakke]]="DHL");"PK3SE";AND(SEARCH("Koli";[@[Pakke type]]);[@[DHL eller pakke]]="Pakke";[@[Rumfang m³]]>0,1);"PK2SE";AND(SEARCH("Koli";[@[Pakke type]]);[@[DHL eller pakke]]="Pakke";[@[Rumfang m³]]<=0,1);"PK1SE")

Comment: Should be made into 1 formula